# NetSuite: how can the Bulk Process history be monitored for success/failure after a scripted process completes?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have a map/reduce script which processes a queue of item receipts against various transaction types. For purchase orders and transfer orders, the load/transform/save of an item receipt returns with a new item receipt ID.

For **inbound shipment receipts**, there is no .transform() available: ref. [NetSuite documentation on scripting Inbound Shipments](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_1490344833.html). After loading a RECEIVE_INBOUND_SHIPMENT record type from the originating Inbound Shipment, updating lines, and saving the result, a **Bulk Processing** event is created, rather than a finished item receipt. The NetSuite bulk processing queue(?)/engine(?) takes care of the item receipt creation in the background.

Here's the problem: I need to detect success/failure and mark the queued record as complete. The returned value from the .save() is not an ID of a new item receipt, nor the ID of a bulk process task, but the ID of the originating inbound shipment record.

It appears that I have to somehow asynchronously sweep through the bulk processing queue and figure out what happened. I am fetching the bulk processing queue via a .query() call at the start of the reduce() and summarize(), but the queue doesn't reflect any new rows or changes. Maybe that's "too soon"?

Are there some events firing related to Bulk Process in NetSuite that I can hook and update my queue with the SUCCESS/FAILURE message?

The only solution I've hit thus far is to write a script or workflow after submit of a new item receipt in the *Bulk Processing* context--but that only gets me a Success message. I can't figure out how to detect Failure in the bulk process queue.

Any pointers?